# How to create an overload API or function in Actix-web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

**Background**

I need to create a couple of endpoints for an API service project. These API can accept encrypted and un-encrypted one (for development). Both parameters then are passed into a same function. For example:

1. `/api/movie/get` with encrypted parameter (for production)
2. `/dev/movie/get` with un-encrypted parameter (for development)

**Current implementation in actix_web**

I use actix_web and routes (not macro) to provide path routing. Modified from the sample code below

```
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, Responder};

async fn index() -> impl Responder {
    "Hello world!"
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new().service(
            // prefixes all resources and routes attached to it...
            web::scope("/app")
                // ...so this handles requests for `GET /app/index.html`
                .route("/index.html", web::get().to(index)),
        )
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

For each API endpoint, I had to create 2 functions, such as:

```
/// for encrypted one
/// PATH: /api/movie/get
pub async fn handle_get_movie(
    app_data: Data<AppState>,
    Json(payload): Json<EncryptedPayload>,
) -> Result<impl Responder, Error> {

    // decrypt the content
    // this is the only difference between un-encrypted and encrypted endpoint
    let params = payload
        .unload::<GetMovieInf>()
        .map_err(|_| MainError::Malformatted)?;

    // other codes here....

    Ok(Json(ReplyInf {ok: true}))
}
```

```
/// for un-encrypted one 
/// PATH: /dev/movie/get
pub async fn handle_get_movie(
    app_data: Data<AppState>,
    Json(payload): Json<UnencryptedPayload>,
) -> Result<impl Responder, Error> {

    // other codes here. These codes are exactly identical with the above function...

    Ok(Json(ReplyInf {ok: true}))
}
```

**Questions**

Since both functions are similar, does it possible to combine them both into a single function ? a function "overload" maybe ?

The problem is this line `Json(payload): Json<UnencryptedPayload>` in the parameter function. I tried to use generics like `Json<T>`. this doesn't work.

I can use the environment variable to control which should be active (`EncryptedPayload` or `UnencryptedPayload`). I can use one path for each endpoint (eg: `/api/movie/get`) and don't have to write the same functionality twice.

Comment: I would just extract the common logic out into a separate function and then call it from each handler.

Comment: @JoeClay well... I eventually did it, but still a unified API would be nice.